# Parallel Port Java Programming

Tags: java, parallel-port

how to control data bits of a parallel port via java.actually i am making a project on " WEB BASED POWER HANDLING" in which i have to control devices remotely from other machines over internet through parallel port progrmming.any help?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a standard Java API for handling the parallel port so you will have to have the underlying operating system help you.

Most operating system allows talking to external devices - Windows through the "PRN" magic name, Linux through various /dev/files - so if you can do what you want through that, then you are fine.

If not, you will need to find native code that can do what you need, and link it into your Java application through JNI, which can be a very interesting experience.  If so, you might get a better result by using a native technology to the platform in question to do this.  Most modern languages have web servers as a standard component.

Comment: I think that the special device files are almost useless without the ability to do `ioctl()` (or whatever the equivalent is on Windows...). I don't think the OP could avoid using native code completely...

Answer (score 2):

Java does not support parallel ports - or any other kind of hardware port, for that matter - out of the box. You will need an external library that contains the native code necessary to communicate with the port of your choice.

You might want to have a look at the [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) library. It seems that it supports parallel ports to a degree...

Answer (score -1):

Do yourself a favour, forget the antique and obsolete Printer port. Since a couple of yea5rs, most computers don't even have one any longer. Check out USB-connected gadgets, such as Arduino: [Make a USB Device, Control It In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159253/make-a-usb-device-control-it-in-java)

Comment: guys thanks for the help till now but what i really need is to simply send data bits( on and Off) to the 8 data pins available in the parallel port via java. Can u help in the programming there?