# How to perform an external call in a Java FX application to build and run an arduino program?

Tags: java, javafx, arduino

I am creating a hardware based human computer interaction air mouse device for the physically disabled people using the Arduino, voice recognition module , accelerometer and gyroscope sensors for which I need to make a JavaFX application to externally run the Arduino program . How can I implement this external call.

I've tried searching different websites. But I couldn't find anything that best suits my needs.

Comment: Did you try entering the first nine words of your title into a search engine?

Comment: @VGR I googled . But couldn't find anything how I can use external calling to actually upload the code onto the arduino and execute it. I only found things such as external calls to run ".exe" files. But not uploading or executing ".ino" files onto the arduino board.

Comment: What you have looked at that did not suit your needs? I was curious myself and just did some quick googling.. Have you had a look at Arduino Serial? "Serial is used for communication between the Arduino board and a computer or other devices." [Arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/Serial)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a USB Device, Control It In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159253/make-a-usb-device-control-it-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino IDE can compile & upload sketches via specific 
[Command Line Arguments](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc). Call the IDE using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), passing the correct arguments. Make sure to check the return code for errors and display the standard output/error streams.

You can use one of several [Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901015/4730685) or [JavaComm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/SerialPort.html) to access the serial port to exchange data.